# removing single line SQL comments using java

Tags: java, sql

How do you remove single line SQL comments froma single string using Java?
I tried something like the following, but this doesnot seem to be fool-proof.
Need a regex that will account for '--' characters when they appear as literals in select statements as in select '--hi' from dual.

```
   protected String removeSingleLineComments(String sql)
{

  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("--[^\r\n]*");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sql);


  while(matcher.find()) {


      if((matcher.start()==0) || (matcher.start()>0 && sql.charAt(matcher.start()-1) != '\''))
  {
      sql =sql.replace(sql.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()), "").trim();


  }
  }
  return sql;

}
```

Comment: What is the patterns of your SQL sample? Is it always 1 line SQL? Multi-line SQL but you only want to remove last line comment? How is your code failing?

Comment: Uh, are you sure you that your end-of-line is always _both_ of the characters?  Not every platform uses the same ones.  If the value of the `Pattern` is hardcoded, you can make it a constant instance.  `String` has a `replaceAll()` method, which would take the input string (no `Pattern`/`Matcher` needed); your `if` clause can and should be part of the regex.

Comment: I am aware of String.replaceAll(). However I need to handle '--' appearing as part of text blocks as in - select '--hi' from dual. With my regex, the text '--hi' would be filtered out as well. I need a new pattern to account for text blocks

Answer (score 1):

Regexp should be: `--.*$`, to match end of line in a portable way.

Answer (score 1):

Just split the string by carriage return then split each line by "--":

```
  private static String removeInLineSQLComments(String sql) {
      StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      for (String line : sql.split("\n")) {
          stringBuilder.append(line.split("--")[0]).append("\n");
      }
      return stringBuilder.toString();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pattern looks okay. Matcher is used as:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(([^']+|'[^']*')*)--[^\r\n]*");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find()) {
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "$1");
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);
return sb.toString();
```

The pattern does:

```
^((
    [^']+
|
    '[^']*'
)*)
--[^\r\n]*
```

Line start, repetition of either non-apostrophe chars or string literal.
The extra parenthesis is to have $1 take the remaining SQL.

Comment: In my code, I also need to check to see if '--' is not part of a text block as - select '--hi' from dual. In this case, my pattern will not work. How do I modify the regex to account for text blocks?

Comment: Okay considered string literals of, not considering backslashes.

Comment: My string is something like this - String a ="--hi\nselect '--hi' from dual\n--morecomments\n'. Will this regex still work?

Comment: Yes. One can always try it out in a small program.